# Online Website Backup Solution?

Tags: backups

i am managing Lil bit big online teaching website(1gb).
it was bit pain when we talk about getting backup from the my Host.
and my internet speed also dam slow. because of it i am currently use my hotfile premium account Remote upload facility to back up my site. but the problem is these hotfile backup files life time is too short(30 days). i need alternative for this.

my requirements.

1. ability to upload 1gb file.
2. Remote upload facility smiler to hotfile.com
3. long life time for files(3-6 months).
4. good download speed smiler to hotfile.com
5. can pay nearly $10 per month

please help me to solve this.

Comment: You may get a better response from http://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

Possibly rethink your overall backup.....

1)  Do ALL the files change quite a bit?  On my company's app, there's a couple of folders that get updated frequently, the others, VERY infrequently.  So we only do daily backups of the files that change.  ++Big Bandwidth Savings

2)  Doesn't the host offer some solution?  I'm a big fan of AISO.net...they will do hourly snapshots as part of the solution.  Other hosting offers nightly backups as part of the solution.

3)  1GB is a LOT of data...certainly more media than application files.  Could you split out media hosting to an easier to backup solution?  Perhaps serve up media via the cloud?

4)  Can anything be optimized for quicker delivery AND save you time with the backup?  A recent audit of my app found HUGE file size improvements with basic optimization practices. ++big bandwidth AND backup savings

5)  Can anything be deleted?  Sounds silly, but many companies leave huge folders of garbage out there.  Spring cleaning anyone?

Really, any quality host with shell access could be used to park files.  You could easily build a cron to upload to a GoDaddy or HostGator account or the like, though you'd want to check TOS to make sure it was kosher.

Comment: it have lot of mp3 & pdf files collection.

Answer (score 0):

I use [JungleDisk](https://www.jungledisk.com/business/) ($5 / month) and [Amazon S3](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/) (extremely affordable) to do nightly backups.  The great thing about the setup is that JungleDisk can be configured so that you are only backing up CHANGES to your files.  That way, if a file doesn't change from one day to the next it doesn't get backed up.

There is free software that can be used in conjunction with a cloud storage service like Amazon as well.  [RSync](http://www.samba.org/rsync/) is thrown around quite a bit, although implementation is obviously a little more technical.

Answer (score 0):

Mozy is good and costs $5/month. I can recommend it.

Comment: did Mozy have Remote upload facility or some thing slimier to it.